# MAX(someAttribute) or SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, count

I have a table, with lots of rows (more than `5,000,000,000`), and I want to get the exact number of rows, but as the table has an atrribute called `ID` like:

```
    ID              someAtt someAtt2  someAtt3  
-----------------------------------------------  
    1               32      DOWN      45
    ...
    ...
    (lots of rows)
    ...
    ...   
    5,000,000,000   25      MOVE      40
```

What is it the best aproach to get the exact number (here 5,000,000,000)?
using `max(ID)` or `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNT(*)`. `MAX(ID)` will give you an inaccurate count if a row is ever deleted, while `COUNT` won't. If you use `COUNT(*)` instead of a specific column name, the database server will decide on which column to use to optimize the operation.

Comment: SQL Server will also do this if you choose any non nullable column or expression.

Answer (score 2):

If you can live with a potentially slightly out of date count, you could also look into the system catalog views in SQL Server. Especially on a large table like yours, this value would be retrieved significantly faster than actually doing a `COUNT(*)` on your table - but it might not be 100% accurate:

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCount
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME = 'YourLargeTableNameHere'
    AND i.index_id <= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try them both and compare the performance, but I'd default to the `COUNT` method, as it is more obvious and unlikely to ever give the wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

Definitelly a COUNT(*), because those IDs may have gaps in future, and when coding, it is advised that not do things that may change in a future to avoid subtle malfunctions hard to find (those little assumptions are the ones that are harder to debug after).

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use COUNT(*) - see Ken Whites answer for the reasons.

If I wanted an alternative I consider updating the Statistics and using the row count from that see this [SQL Hacks page](http://www.sqlhacks.com/Optimize/Fast_Count) .

For the reasons offered by others (gaps in the ID sequence) I would not use the MAX(ID)), also this could conceivably cause a full table scan, as the count(*) might, but without the advantage of accuracy.